# changing the value of a variable's color

Tags: javascript

i am building a server side program using. this will not touch the internet so i am not concerned about security issues. 
i got it to write as .docx. What i would like to do is be able to change the color of the value of a variable before it is written to the .docx

```
function bla(){
var s= fso.CreateTextfile('bla Report'.docx", true);
var str ="              This is supposed to be green";
var str = str.fontcolor("green"); // this is what will not fire properly 
s.WriteLine("");    
s.WriteLine(""+str+"")
s.WriteLine("");
}
```

Comment: You have mismatched quote marks and it looks like you're either trying to write C# or using a library that I'm not familiar with.

Comment: This does not seem vanilla-js. Are you using a library or something? Please tag your question properly.

Comment: @Oriol I think it's a version of javascript called "jscript" executed in a [windows script host](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9bbdkx3k%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) environment.

Answer (score 0):

The [String.prototype.fontcolor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fontcolor) method has been deprecated and no longer supported. It may very well be that the JE on your server does not support it.

The other thing to note is that the string generated uses html markup. You may need to change `.docx` to `.html` if it is written in HTML.

A simple function to mark up plain text as a span element with a color could be

```
function spanColor( text, color)
{  return '<span style="color: ' + color + ';">' + text + '</span>"'
}
```

FYI and as already noted in comment, the quotes around `'bla Report'.docx"` need to be corrected ("bla Report.docx" perhaps). Also check what you intend by the expression `"" + str + ""` as the double quoted null strings have no effect if `str` is already a string.